# Is it true that big embedded companies are "forced" to use old programming standards/compilers?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, standards, policy

Our lecturer told us that in completing our assignments, we are only allowed to use C++98 / C99 standards, by specifying the correct flags to the compiler we can ensure we don't break this rule.

I understand that this is so people can learn "real" C or C++, whichever they chose, and exercise this skill without any help from new language features whatsoever (I don't agree, but who am I to argue).

When asking my lecturer why this rule he answered (after knowing I'm not satisfied with the above answer): "because big old companies like ASML that work with embedded devices have old codebases that (will) *can* break when switching to C11/C++11).

I asked for a specific real world / practical example of a piece of code, that compiles both in C99/C11 (or C++98/C++11), is standard compliant (C99/C++98), but behaviorally very different when in binary form - to sum it up, the question has not been answered. If the statement that companies are stuck to old compilers and standards is true, can someone provide such piece of code that I want to see for myself?

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE) is talk by someone writing a Commodore 64 game in C++17. So no, the statement is not true in general. One *can* write embedded software in a modern language.

Comment: If all your libraries are written in C++98 - it will cost a lot to migrate them all, and there's not much gain for doing so.  For this reason, businesses that have existed for a few years are forced to do so for economic reasons.

Comment: Yeah from what I know companies just use gcc, clang or any of the popular compilers, and if they have a "unique" platform then the only limit is the compilers abilities (because there are no newer compilers, which support newer standards, and new C++ standards ofcourse aim for 100% backwards ocmpatibility)

Comment: Also - some platforms, old versions of solaris for example, don't have a c++03 compiler.

Comment: New compilers are producing binary-incompatible code with some old libraries (different ABI). Large companies have no source code of some proprietary libraries and they cant get it/update it

Comment: That statement is not really true. While there are old code-bases, especially C11 added features which are especially useful for the embedded world (namely atomics). Problem is that many commercial compilers don't support them. But on modern MCUs like MSP430 or all ARM variants, you can use modern compilers like gcc (can't tell about clang, but for the larger ARMs it should be fine, too) work fine and often generate even better code with equal quality than expensive commercial tools. My advice: go for the gcc (or clang) way, where reasonable prefer MCUs which are supported by them.

Comment: While it is true that recent gcc/clang will usually support any popular target MCU it is also true that in many cases developers are not given a choice of the compiler. It is common to get a hardware platform from some 3rd party together with BSP (board support package) which dictates a particular choice of tools and base OS. The business will not tolerate developers wasting numerous man-hours just to get "some shiny new language features".

Comment: C and C++ are very different here. The C committee are extremely conservative/afraid and seem to have nothing but backwards-compatibility on their minds. The C++ committee on the other hand, have no concerns about anything, which has caused C++ to escalate into an extremely complex, meta-programming hell. It has always suffered from heavy reliance on meta programming, but has now gone completely out of hand. I think C++ is a lost cause; in the real world, you can't afford to sit around doing programming for programmings own sake, but you actually have to produce a working application.

Comment: One example is Linux kernel. Almost all code target gnu98. When gcc switched default to gnu11, kernel maintainers patched every single makefile to force gnu98. Now although any c standard are allowed, very little code choose gnu99 or gnu11.

Comment: Any new keyword introduced to the language can break the old code. If your program uses a variable named 'constexpr' it will not compile with C++11 while it compiled with previous versions.

Comment: @Lundin And yet they made a fatal break in C11: VLAs were mandatory in C99, but made optional in C11.

Comment: @user3528438: What is `gnu98`?? There is no C98 and no such gcc option

Comment: @Olaf No doubt there were some super-conservative people whining to the committee about getting forced to implement VLAs and other such useful features (like stdint.h), so the anxious committee made various features optional. Anyway, the market demand will win this in the end, since few people will buy compilers that lack fundamental features.

Comment: @Lundin: As a strong supporter of VLAs (and other modern features), I hope you are right. But not very positive about a specific major compiler vendor which still sticks with C90. I'd rather call it "lazy"/unwillingly than conservative, though.

Comment: `I asked for  ...., is standard compliant .... ` Don't expect all code held by a company to be standard compliant.... There may very well be non-standard compliant code in the code base that just happens to work fine on a specific system using a specific compiler. Changing compiler may cause such code to stop working.

Comment: @Olaf And as a result, that major compiler vendor has effectively maintained their reputation of someone who only delivers unprofessional junk - a reputation they've had ever since C90 was new. Which probably doesn't concern them much nowadays, when Windows programming in C is rare and they don't target Linux, for obvious reasons. Though ultimately, open source will be the death of all shitty compilers. The only way to stay alive in the commercial compiler business will be to produce higher quality with better documentation & support than the open source alternatives.

Comment: @Lundin: Oh, I took that direction for embedded some time ago already. Not to forget the extended warnings (and features) gcc provides (I'm always scared how little checking commercial compilers do).

Comment: I wouldn't know how to rephrase this question so it wouldn't be less subjective, any tips anyone? The current answers are very good but indeed lack references just like the on hold message states

Answer (score 4):

*I don't know much about the embedded world but a bit of other companies using c++ and having old hardware / platforms*

---

It really depends on the company and the platform they use. But with some effort and open management there should be nothing against having modern c++ everywhere (from the technical point of view)

In several companies I know the developers encourage the move to modern c++ and they are moving more and more.

Sometimes you have to put some more effort in it than "just" installing a new compiler. When you need to deliver to an old platform (e.g. Debian 6) and cannot change the OS you have to manually compile the libstdc++ on that platform and deliver this with your product / have it use the specific one (there are more details but you get the point).

---

So while there maybe are companies stuck to old c++ because of conservative management or the developers not caring about modern c++. There are also more and more companies upgrading. And learning modern c++ is also **not wrong** because the "old" style is usually discouraged in companies who use modern c++.

---

Code maybe "break" when they switch compilers but only on the compilation level and because they used non-standard features/syntax (which some older compilers are more tolerant of). But behavior wise I don't know of something which "silently" breaks (the standard committee is actively trying to avoid this with each change) and you also get more and better warnings with better compilers.

Answer (score 2):

A product in a big company need not be out of a single code base. The code base could be dependent on many other libraries (including 3rd party).

The product code cannot be compiled with the latest compiler unless and until all its dependencies are compiled using that version of the compiler. (At least that is the case with static libraries)

So generally, it is difficult to move to the latest version of compilers for big products having large dependencies. Also there is a big testing overhead that should be incurred after the movement to the latest compiler.

The management would agree in doing the above only when ROI(Return On Investment) is good which is rarely the case for doing so with legacy code.

Comment: Modern C11 compilers also support older versions of the standard. At least with C, there is normally no problem to compile different modules with different versions. Enable all relevant warnings and you should be fine using C11 for user-code.

Comment: It depends on the language. How about the change in the semantics of auto in c++11? When we use auto in c++11 the compiler deduces the type at compile type. Before c++11, it used to be a storage class specifier.

Comment: Which is another reason questions about C **and** C++ are too broad per se (unless they are specifically about interaction between them).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the company, their embedded product line, and their customer base.

Some companies have an entrenched culture, so they insist on using older techniques, even in the face of reasoned technical arguments to update.   Some companies are progressive, and support updating to newer compilers and standards whenever it makes sense (and, conversely, support sticking to older techniques when THAT makes sense).   Some companies are so determined in adopting the latest trend, that they use unproven technologies and compromise the stability of their product lines.

Some embedded products make use of particular hardware components that are no longer in manufacture, and for which there is no cost-effective alternative available through a combination of newer hardware or software.   With hard real time systems, for example, there can be old hardware that meets critical timing constraints, but newer hardware cannot be readily obtained that meets the original requirement.

Some embedded products are of high criticality (safety critical, mission critical, etc) with an active regulatory body that insists on a raft of solid technical evidence being provided before an update will be approved (and a delegate who signs off on such an update without the documented evidence will be legally liable if something goes wrong in the field - such as the system killing someone due to a timing error).   That documentation can be highly expensive to produce.  A company with such a product may find it is more cost effective to stick with the older (accepted by the regulator) development environment.   Having to pay a few million dollars in order to justify updating to a newer compiler tends to put a crimp in a company's willingness to fork out for producing new evidence that justifies using the new compiler.

Ultimately, to sell a product, it is necessary to convince a paying customer to pay out for it.    If a large percentage of customers of the older system are not willing to pay for an update - after all, the existing system works fine - there is no justification for the vendor to update - unless they can make the change cost-neutral for the customer (which is often hard to achieve when updating a critical embedded system, unless the vendor is willing to absorb a lot of cost).   Similarly, a key customer might have actually PAID for development and then maintenance of the existing system, and may consider that continuing to pay for maintenance of the existing system is better value for money than paying for an update, and going through the process of providing evidence it works as required.

Answer (score 1):

Just this year I have used two different compilers that are more than 20 years old.  This wasn't for new designs, however.  It was for maintenance of products that are also about 20 years old.  Embedded products can be supported for decades.  In one of my cases, a hardware component went obsolete, which required a small redesign, which required a software update.  In the other case the hardware design had to be updated for RoHS compliance, and the resulting design required a software update.  In both cases I believe it would have been more work and more risk to use a modern compiler.  That old code and binary has been proven with 20 years of on-the-job experience.

In a third case the microcontroller went obsolete and we redesigned with an FPGA running a soft processor.  In this case some porting was required and I used a different, more modern compiler.  But I was still pretty cautious about how much I changed the original source code.

I wouldn't say I've been "forced" by policy to use these old compilers and avoid new compiler features.  When you're maintaining old designs it can be a matter of practicality.  Or it can be a choice to make fewer changes in order to avoid inadvertently breaking something that has been proven to work.

For new designs we use modern compilers.  And I've never had to restrict myself to an older C standard.

PS: For an even harsher experience you could limit yourself to compilers that work only on Windows XP and a debugger that requires a parallel port on your PC.